# referencing external json files in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm using webpack template with vue. 
In my application I want to reference external .json files (on the same server) that vue application then loops and displays.

The problem is that once I run the build step, the content of these .json files gets embedded in applications javascript so when I replace them (the .json files will be changed several times a day), the code doesn't change.

I've tried putting them in the static folder but this doesn't help.

Currently I'm referencing files like this:

```
import JsonProd from '../../json/prod.json'
import JsonRelease from '../../json/release.json'
import JsonDevel from '../../json/devel.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selectedComponent: 'Devel',
      activeTab: 1,
      devel: JsonDevel,
      prod: JsonProd,
      release: JsonRelease
    }
  },
```

Comment: This is the intended functionality. Runtime JavaScript has access to the filesystem, but browser JavaScript does not. Imagine how insecure it would be if your browser could interact directly with the servers filesystem. You'll need to re-architect your anticipated design.

Comment: You need to fetch the json files with ajax during runtime.

Comment: use copy-webpack-plugin to have the raw files.